# Quick Reference Section

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As a new 'regular user' on Stack Overflow I've found it very difficult to find some types of 'How To' information that I think would help myself and others to become more proficient contributors.

By trawling through a lot of pages on the site and reading posts in the Help Center 'Find out more about...' section I've discovered a lot about how to form questions and provide answers, but these answers tend towards social and ethical points, which of course are important, but they don't cover everything.

There are some things, like technical answers, I had to dig a lot deeper to find (and some I'm still looking for)
An example: 'How to use Code Snippets' I found in a Stack Overflow Blog post from 2014.
Perhaps this information is somewhere else and I've missed it _ but not through lack of trying to find it!

Other elements and actions of the site I feel I only stumbled over.
An example: I had a couple of edits down-voted by moderators but (again unless I missed it) there was no notification this had happened, and when I realised what had happened I couldn't find an area of the site that related to how to edit properly. There's information in Help Center about losing reputation but I was much more interested in learning how to edit properly _

Everything happens over time, I get that. 
As contributors become more experienced and 'learn the ropes' being part of Stack Overflow community becomes easier. Hopefully you even get to know where the technical 'How To' info can be found!
But asking in META about a Quick Reference Section isn't about cutting corners, just making it a bit easier for 'newbies' to find technical information about how SO works

Thanks : )

Comment: Check out the [meta-tag:faq] tag here on Meta.

Comment: wow _ I really searched for FAQ and couldn't find one _ thanks @Stijn

Comment: @Maik did you search on stack itself? Cause... It's bad. Use a Google search, target stack's site, and search. Way more efficient :)

Comment: I was worried about asking this question but I'm really pleased I did _ I've already found some answers from FAQ that I couldn't find before _ and yours a great tip too @Patrice _ Normally I'll question Google and if I see SO in search results I naturally go there first _ but targeting SO is more 'refined' ; )
Much gratitude for these responses guys

Comment: @maik of course! I know meta has a bit of a bad rep... But if the question is sensible, well explained, we don't bite :). Keep that attitude and you'll be able to get a lot of good benefits from meta. In the meantime, welcome and happy SOing :)

Comment: @Patrice just to add to "*Use a Google search, target stack's site*", the syntax for that is `search text site:stackoverflow.com` - that will give you results for `search text` and limit them to come only from `stackoverflow.com`. It's really the better way to search SO. You can also use subdomains, if you want - `site:meta.stackoverflow.com` will give results for meta, but not the main site.

Comment: BTW there are two FAQs: one general [for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931), second specifically [for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225).

Comment: useful links @Pshemo _ thanks!